# How do I bind a lookup combobox?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, combobox, binding

My WPF4 combobox dropdown list is incorrectly displaying the class name of my EF4 entity. Here is the relevant XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myEntitiesViewSource"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEntitiesViewSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryDescription" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" />
```

Here is the code in my Window_Loaded event:

```
var categoryList = from p in _context.Categories
                  orderby p.CategoryNumber
                  select p;

System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource myEntitiesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("myEntitiesViewSource")));
// Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
myEntitiesViewSource.Source = categoryList;
```

My database has a many to many relationship between Projects and Categories with a join table called ProjectCategories. The Categories entity was automagically created as a single entity to represent two database tables:

1) the lookup table of Categories containing an ID, CategoryDescription and CategoryNumber and

2) the join table ProjectCategories **containing only two fields** - the IDs from the tables Projects and Categories. The entity model lives in a separate project from my WPF window.

My goal is to allow the user to select a CategoryDescription from the dropdown list, then click an Add Category button to add the selected Category to a separate list of ProjectCategories. With the current code I see the correct CategoryDescription in the combobox text area but the dropdown list  displays only the entity class name Categories (preceded by it's namespace) multiple times!

**How do I make this simple lookup combobox bind correctly and display a list of CategoryDescriptions and a SelectedValue of CategoryID?** Note: I'd accept a code only approach leaving out the CollectionViewSource in XAML if it's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I asked this question and have answered it myself. There was nothing wrong with my code or XAML. **The problem was caused by the use of a third party theme** to style my controls. Once I removed the theme the combobox binding problem went away. For more details [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702773/wpf4-is-this-indictment-of-devexpress-wpf-controls-valid-and-what-is-a-good-alte?tab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Category}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

Instead of using a Selected Value, I would store the whole object. The selected value approach is old ASP style for my taste.

`SelectedItem="{Binding Category}"` is your Category object. Basically it has stored the selected item of the ComboBox.

When the user clicks a button for example, you can fire a Command from the ViewModel and you will have the corresponding selected Category object.